# Implementing a Stack in Java for a technical interview

Tags: java, interview-questions, linked-list, stack

This code is based off the Stack implementation in Chapter 3 of *Cracking The Coding Interview*. I modified the code to make it compile and give me the correct output. I'd appreciate any feedback on code style and correctness, assuming that I write this code in a technical interview.

The pseudocode from *Cracking the Coding Interview*, which is implemented using a linked list:

> ```
> class Stack {
>
>     Node top;
>
>     Object pop() {
>         if (top != null) {
>             Node item = top.data;
>             top = top.next;
>             return item;
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     void push(Object item) {
>         Node t = new Node(item);
>         t.next = top;
>         top = t;
>     }
>
>     Object peek() {
>         return top.data;
>     }
> }
> ```

My code:

```
public class Stack {
    Node first;
    Node last;

    public Stack(Node f, Node l) {
        first = f;
        last = l;
        first.next = last;
    }

    public Stack() {
        first.next = last;
    }

    public void push(Object data) {
        if(first == null) {
            first = new Node(data, null);
        }
        else {
            last.next = new Node(data, null);
            last = last.next;
        }

    }

    public Object pop() {
        if(first == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        else { 
            Object item = last.data;
            Node cur = first;
            while (cur.next.next != null) {
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            last = cur;
            return item;
        }
    }

    public Object peek() {
        if(first == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        Object item = last.data;
        return item;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stack = new Stack(new Node(1, null), new Node(2, null));
        stack.push(3);
        System.out.println(stack.peek() == 3);
        stack.pop();
        System.out.println(stack.peek() == 2);
    }

    private static class Node {
        Object data;
        Node next;

        private Node(Object d, Node n) {
            data = d;
            next = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A stack should not know about the first element. A stack only know about the last element that was pushed, so the `Stack` object itself should only have one `Node` called `last`. <s>Because of this, the constructor should be changed as well to only take one `Node` ex: `public Stack(Node node)`.</s>

**Edit:** As @vnp says, `Node` is private, so it cannot be created outside this class. Either create a constructor which takes an `Object`, or don't create any constructors and always create an empty `Stack`.

This constructor doesn't do anything and will throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
public Stack() {
    first.next = last;
}
```

In `pop()`, you shouldn't need to do any fancy `while` loops. Just check if `last` is `null` and if not, get `last`'s `data` and set `last` to `last.next`:

```
public Object pop() {
    if(last == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Object item = last.data;
        last = last.next;
        return item;
    }   
}
```

In `push()`, you should simply set `last` to be the new `Node`, and have it point to the old `last` as it's `next`:

```
public void push(Object data) {
    last = new Node(data, last);
}
```

In `peek()`, you can change `first` to `last` and simply return `last.data`:

```
public Object peek() {
    if(last == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return last.data;
}
```

One final point: you should not give your variables one character names like `d`, `n`, `l`, and `f`. If the variables in your constructor should have the same name as the private member variables, then give them the same name and prefix the members with `this` to differentiate them. For example, you can change the `Node` constructor to:

```
private Node(Object data, Node node) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = node;
}
```

Comment: `public Stack(Node node)` is impossible because `class Node` is private. I'd just construct an empty stack.

Comment: Oops you are right.

Comment: " and will probably throw a `NullPointerException`" No, it won't.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca actually, I just tested the code, and it does throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: There shouldn't be any answer to this question that doesn't at least *mention* the use of generics.

Comment: `return -1` is good when the return type is `int`; but not when it is `Object`.

Comment: @KenzieTogami `return -1` is probably never good, but I assumed (wrongly) that this was some sort of homework problem, and `-1` was the correct error value or something. However, many other people have addressed the `-1` thing (and the generics thing, @BobbyDigital), and I upvoted their answers rather than stealing what makes their answers unique and useful. Also see [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-is-code-review-doing-right-now#answer-994): "Not all of our answers have to hit everything that is wrong with the code."

Comment: @stie Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 14):

As usual, revewing a design rather than code.

- As coded, `pop` takes time proportional to the current stack size. It could and should take constant time. Hint: reverse the semantics of `node.next` (BTW, `first` becomes redundant).
- I don't think that `pop/peek` returning `-1` on empty stack is a good idea. A value of `-1` is a valid result of popping from a stack of integers. Why not return `null`? Throwing an exception is also a viable option.
- A client of this implementation cannot use a 2-argument constructor (`class Node` is private). Therefore it doesn't have a right to exist.

Comment: Throwing an exception is not simply a *viable* option, it's the *correct* one on a `pop`. Popping an empty stack is an invalid operation - specifically, a stack underflow. With `peek` you could maybe be a bit more lenient, but better to be consistent.

Comment: Aaronnaught, "correct" statement is an absolute statement, but throwing an exception is not always the correct option. I would consider taking a queue from [the Java Deque interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) on this one.

Comment: Depending on your design goals, it might be ok to store `null` values in the `Stack` Then you need `Exceptions`. If you would even need magical values like `-1`, at least use a public constant for it.

Comment: Any value that could be misinterpreted as a valid entry in the stack (like `-1`) is not a useful error code.  If i can't easily tell the difference between legitimately popping a value and underflowing the stack, that's a design error.  `null` isn't currently an option either, since the stack allows it to be pushed.  (It could be, though, if `push(null)` threw an `IllegalArgumentException` or something.  But then you're already throwing exceptions; might as well throw a "stack underflow" exception as well.)

Comment: @corsiKa taking a *queue* from the deque ;)

Answer (score 10):

- I would look at this code and think you hadn't messed with Java since before 1.5.  You should really be using generics, particularly for a collection-type class like a stack.
- Any value you allow to be pushed onto the stack, is useless as an error code.

  Consider the following code:

  ```
  Stack s = new Stack();
  s.push(-1);

  ... do lots of pushes and pops ...

  Object value = s.pop();
  ```

  Did i just get an error, or legitimately pop a `-1`?

  Either prevent the pushing of `null` and use that as an error code, or throw an exception if there's nothing to pop.  The latter is usually preferable.

Answer (score 6):

Stacks are so simple you can practically write them directly from specifications:

1. `empty` is a `Stack<T>`
2. `push(T, Stack<T>)` is a `Stack<T>`
3. `isEmpty(empty)` -> `true`
4. `isEmpty(push(t, s))` -> `false`
5. `top(empty)` -> error
6. `top(push(t, s))` -> `t`
7. `pop(empty)` -> error
8. `pop(push(t, s))` -> `s`

This lends itself to the following minimal (immutable) implementation:

```
public interface Stack<T> {
    // Rule 1
    static final Empty EMPTY = Empty.INSTANCE; 

    // Rule 2
    public Stack<T> push(T value) { return new Push<>(value, this); }

    boolean isEmpty();

    Stack<T> pop();

    T top();
}

class Empty<T> implements Stack<T> {
    protected static final Empty INSTANCE = new Empty();

    // Rule 3
    public boolean isEmpty() { return true; }

    // Rule 7
    public Stack<T> pop() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can not pop an empty stack"); }

    // Rule 5
    public T top() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can not take the top of an empty stack");}
}

class Push<T> implements Stack<T> {
    private final T top;
    private final Stack<T> pop;

    Push(T top, Stack<T> pop) {
        this.top = top;
        this.pop = pop;
    }

    // Rule 4
    public boolean isEmpty() { return false; }

    // Rule 8
    public Stack<T> pop() { return pop; }

    // Rule 6
    public T top() { return top; }
}
```

Comment: How do you start a stack? There's no accessible constructors and the `EMPTY` is `package-private`?

Comment: Stack<Integer> intStack = Stack.EMPTY.push(7).push(10);

Comment: But Stack.EMPTY is `package-private`, is this not supposed to be public?

Comment: `Stack` is an interface, so all members are implicitly public, including the `EMPTY` field.

Comment: Oh, I'm still not used to that, even though I've known about it for months. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the design problems mentioned by @vnp:

Any algorithm using a stack contains a `while the stack is not empty` somewhere, so you have to have a public `boolean isEmpty()` method.

Unless you disallow `null` values, returning `null` as a result code is not acceptable, even then inadvisable. You should throw some relevant `RuntimeException` (as suggested by @Aaronaught), preferebly from the standard libraries: e.g. `NoSuchElementException` or `EmptyStackException` etc. If you don't have Java reference documentation available, don't know the *modus operandi*, if it is a whiteboard interview for example, you can throw `IllegalStateException`. (Every Java programmer should know basic OOP exceptions: `IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException`... by heart.)

Answer (score 3):

Most important, I won't hire someone who claims to be a Java programmer unless he knows generics and uses them properly.  This is 10-year-old technology, people.  Get with the program.

Second, using "-1" as an error return is just dumb.  What if someone pushes -1?  Use null (and forbid pushing it).

Third, why are you keeping track of the bottom of the stack?  Seems like a waste of effort, unless I'm missing something.

Finally, the way you are implementing `pop` is just bananas.  The second most common call, and it is O(n)?

A stack is a single-linked list, with only a few methods implemented.  Think about that.